# Use add-in command execute function to display dialog

Tags: javascript, office-js, outlook-web-addins

Currently, I'm using the Execute Function add-in command to display a dialog which shows our custom page. I expect that dialog should only be manually closed by user, but I'm experiencing something different.

Firstly I used this code to display the dialog:

```
this.openDialog = function(event) {
  var dlgOptions = { height: 80, width: 80, displayInIframe: true };
  var myUrl = "someURL";

  var callback = function(asyncResult) {
    if (asyncResult.status !== Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
      event.completed();
      return;
    }
    var dialog = asyncResult.value;
    dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogEventReceived, function(dialogEvent) {
      event.completed();
    });
  };
  Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(myUrl, dlgOptions, callback);
};
```

I got the dialog loaded with my custom page, but I also got some issues:

1. On OWA, the dialog hangs after 5 minutes
2. On desktop client, the dialog is automatically closed after 5 minutes

I found this post: [Office.js dialog makes Outlook hang after 5 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46139879/office-js-dialog-makes-outlook-hang-after-5-minutes), but that's not what I'm looking for. I just need my dialog to be there until user closes it, so I tried it another way:

```
this.openDialog = function(event) {
  var dlgOptions = { height: 80, width: 80, displayInIframe: true };
  var myUrl = "someURL";

  var callback = function(asyncResult) {
    event.completed();
  };
  Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(myUrl, dlgOptions, callback);
};
```

This time, it works as I expected on the desktop client, but for OWA, the dialog hangs right after it's opened.

How can I have the dialog working as expected for both platforms?

Comment: event.completed terminates the running addinCommand and would hang the dialog since its parent was terminated. You should register for dialog close handler in the callback and only call event.completed after close handler has been invoked.Check documentation here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/master/docs/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins.md and a sample here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Dialog-API-Simple-Example/

Comment: Thank you. I did that in my first approach and it give me the 5 minutes "issue". Is there any way I can have a dialog last for more than 5 minutes?

Comment: Unfortunately, for Execute Function add-in commands, the add-in and any opened display dialogs are automatically closed after 5 minutes if event.completed() hasn't been called before then. The fact that the dialog hangs is a bug which we will address as soon as we can. Currently, there's no way to leave the dialog open for more than 5 minutes, but we will consider this feature when going through our planning process.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Is there any update for "leave the dialog open for more than 5 minutes"?