# Can not close Dialog API dialog in ItemSend event, if waiting after a few minutes

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We are developing a web-technologies Outlook Add-in that works with Office 365.

The app opens up a dialog via Dialog API in ItemSend event - if the user waits a few minutes on that dialog, the user can not close the dialog.  If the dialog is closed quickly, no issues.

Script debugger is showing Access is denied errors.

SCRIPTS: Access is denied.
File: Xframe.html, Line: 1, Column: 1

SCRIPTS: Access is denied.
File: xframe, Line 1, Column: 1

SCRIPTS: Access is denied.
File: dlg_external.html, Line: 1, Column: 1

Comment: We did more research and found something that sounded similar:
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46139879/office-js-dialog-makes-outlook-hang-after-5-minutes
But hopefully someone can dig into why Outlook Add-in API is behaving like this.

Comment: Is the user waiting for about 5-minutes? How is the user closing the dialog? By clicking on the "X" at the top-right corner of the dialog window or by interacting with the page displayed in the dialog window?

Comment: Yes, about 5 minutes.  The user is clicking 'X' at the top right corner.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that because the onsend app is opening the dialog, the app has to be aware of this 5 minute time limit, and close its dialog(s) and stop processing before the time expires.  We put a timer in our app for this, and it will give a timeout message.